# setup up ssh connection with 3 Ubuntu machines to bypass a firewall

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ufw

I have 3 machines, here are the IP addresses of each of them with their ssh port :

**first device IP:** `192.168.1.2`

**second device IP"** `192.168.1.3` port `22822`

**third device IP:**  `192.168.1.4`  port `22`

I want to SSH with the first device to the second device and connect with the third device, I don't want to use the `-J`flag and `ProxyCommand` in the SSH command the command to connect the third device should be like this :

`ssh user@192.168.1.3 -p 22822`

I should mention that I already did some `ufw` configurations here are the configurations :

**Configuration in second device:**

`sudo ufw allow 22822`

`sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`

`DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`

`sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22822 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4:22
COMMIT
```

`sudo ufw disable`

`sudo ufw enable`

**Configuration in third device:**

`sudo ufw allow 22`

Comment: we will usually not support people bypassing company security. Please let us know, why you want to break company or business rules and expose it?

Comment: I reside in Iran, where network restrictions limit our access to a free and open internet. I believe that everyone should have access to unrestricted internet connectivity.

Comment: I agree with you about the internet, but what is the business related question in here?

Comment: It's for personal purpose , my VM in cloud just access the free internet and I want to build a VPN for my self just it

Comment: then please ask on superuser, because serverfault will close the question for beeing non business related. there are a lot of vpn tutorials on the internet. if its just a simple way needed, use debian on anykind of your cloud server outside iran, install a simple proxy like ziproxy, configure it to listen on localhost only, setup putty and use port forwarding to localhost to the configured proxy host, thats a 10 minute setup

Comment: @djdomi ok thanks about your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Also here is an alternative way instead of portforwarding you can do (Proxy ssh)
Edit the SSH configuration file on your first device (replace with your username)

```
Host second_device
    HostName 192.168.1.3
    Port 22822
    User your_username

Host third_device
    HostName 192.168.1.4
    Port 22
    User your_username
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p second_device
```

Don't forget to reset sshd and then you could connect to the third device with following command:

```
ssh third_device
```

Comment: but I want to use iptables or ufw to forward incoming ssh connection to the third device

Comment: @nulltogeek Ok than, I think It's gonna work for you, enabale IPFORWARDING on second device via:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22822 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4:22
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

Just logon to the first device with ssh, and then from a shell launch a new ssh session. Keep it simple
You could launch the session in a screen so that you can detach it and use the first server.